# Button Field does not execute when converting it to template Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hello i have this Button Field in a grid-view that perform the below function.

But if i convert this Button Field to template Field the function dose not execute.

The error i get {"Input string was not in a correct format."}.

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="Selectagreement" HeaderText="Select" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="select">
                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                        </asp:ButtonField>
        protected void gvAgreement_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string commandName = e.CommandName.ToString().Trim();
            GridViewRow row = gvAgreement.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
            switch (commandName)
            {
                case "Selectagreement":
                    Label1.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
                    break;
                default: break;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);

        }
    }



                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Selectagreement" Text="select"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Your link button does not have a command argument so e.CommandArgument will be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Hakunamatata in the comments section, the `CommandArgument` is not set for the link button under `<ItemTemplate>`.

However based on your code if you are just after the row index of the corresponding row from where you triggered the link button click, then you could do this.

```
    protected void gvAgreement_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string commandName = e.CommandName.ToString().Trim();

            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

            switch (commandName)
            {
                case "Selectagreement":
                    Label1.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
                    break;
                default: break;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Basically I replaced

```
    GridViewRow row = gvAgreement.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
```

with

```
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
```